# Alter $_GET $_POST using array_map

Tags: php, arrays, get, array-map

I'm going to build simple filter function for $_GET and $_POST. Here is my code.

```
array_map('clean', $_GET);

function clean($el)
{
  $_GET[] = strip_tags($el);
}

var_dump($_GET);

// result
1 => 'One',
2 => 'Two'

// expected
'first' = 'One'
'second' = 'Two'
```

How to keep the same structure for key and values?``

Comment: `$_GET[]` is implicitly creating the indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback to `array_map` needs to *return* a value. `array_map` will call the callback for every value in the array and replace it with the value that is returned. You don't alter the array itself inside the callback.

```
$_GET = array_map('clean', $_GET);

function clean($el) {
    return strip_tags($el);
}

var_dump($_GET);
```

But really, since `strip_tags` already takes one argument and returns one value, this will do the same:

```
$_GET = array_map('strip_tags', $_GET);
```

But really really, a blanket `strip_tags` on all incoming values is a bad idea and doesn't really solve most problems. You need to *escape/sanitize* each value individually depending on what it is and what it is used for. See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score 2):

You misuse `array_map`. You should overwrite here the `$_GET`. and `array_map` expects the callback to return the element of the new array (for this key).

```
$_GET = array_map('clean', $_GET);

function clean($el)
{
     return strip_tags($el);
}
```